# How to automatically format the legend labels? in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, legend

I have to do 10 maps (for a start) with "style" -> "graduate" with quantile mode.

I need to format the label of the different ranges so that the legend looks comprehensible:
Instead of having 1.0000 - 7.0000 I would like to have 1% - 7% without me typing.

In arcgis there is the possibility to format the labels. But I cannot seem to find anything similar in QGIS 1.8. Is it possible with some plugin or other QGIS version ?

Update some years later: the new version seems to have fixed the problem as the answer belows points out.

Comment: Maybe you could do the typing once, save it as a style-template and reuse that on the other maps?

Comment: Sounds great but I still would have to change the intervals, cause those change for each map

Comment: Are you trying to edit the labels on the map, or just in the legend? In case it's on the map, you can label with an expression..

Assuming you are trying to show say, a road slope percentage on a map, based on an attribute 'slope' which holds values in percentages, you can label with 'round("slope",0)||%' That way you can style based on 'quantile ranges', but display the actually data.

If you're after info on how to automatically have the 'label' setting based on style classes altered - I'm clueless there.

Comment: You could use @GR_ 's suggestion and for changing the intervals, just press "Classify" again for each map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three years late perhaps. But this can easily be done in QGIS 2.8, which is the current long term release, onwards.

You can set a legend format, "%1" and "%2" are used as place holders for the lower and upper limits of the range. Other characters can be inserted as needed.

There is also a option to limit the precision, so perhaps to 0 in your case.

[image]

Comment: Well the new version clearly has done great improvements for all these little annoying problems.