# Get round numbers using Natural Breaks (Jenks) classification

Tags: arcmap, symbology, classification

In ArcMap, is there an easier way to get more round numbers when using the Natural Breaks (Jenks) classification in the symbology tab? For example, in the image below I'd want the classes to be 5-140, 141-340, 341-1500, etc. I know I can just go in and manually change the numbers to the closest round numbers, I was just wondering if there is a tool or more automated way to have the software do this for me, as it can be rather time consuming when trying to use >6 classes.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically format the legend labels? in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40760/how-to-automatically-format-the-legend-labels-in-qgis)

Comment: No, a QGIS question is not a duplicate of an ArcGIS question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all your symbols in the same Symbology tab, then right click -> Format Labels...
Set the number of decimal places there and you are good to go!
[image]

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was correct, woudl you mind marking it as accepted by clicking the tick symbol under the vote counter?